# C++ GPS direction confidence algorithm?

Tags: c++, gps, coordinates, noise

I am trying to find some documentation or even any information about a generic method for taking real-time sampling of coordinates and determining the direction of the device.

I have a function:

```
function add(x, y) {
    buffer.push_back(sqrt(pow(x - KNOWN_X, 2) + pow(y - KNOWN_Y, 2)));
}
```

I would like to scan the buffer after every time a new distance is added and check if the device is heading away or towards the known location. The hard part I am facing is the GPS error. I have devices rated at 4.5 gps error radius. So some of the distances will be fluctuating as they are going towards/away. What is a good known algorithm to confidently sample a few of these distances and tell me whether the gap is growing or shrinking?

I looked at a few noise reduction algorithm like Kalman but it is really complicated and hard to tune to achieve results I need.

Comment: why are you xoring stuff with 2?

Comment: Sorry, that is just pseudo code, I will fix it. I meant pow(...)

Answer (score 0):

For determing the direction of the device, you read the "course" attribute of the delivered location.
Sometimes this attribute is called heading.
The heading is not only calculated via positional change, a part is calculated by physical doppler effect, but the exact technik is not published. I have read an patent where it is decribed that more then the simple positional change is considered.

So you should take that value, and not calculate it yourself via position change.

course is acurate if the device moves a bit faster than walking speed.

Comment: How is the heading calculated then? I am essentially getting UTM coordinates with no altitude or heading.. so I need a way to calculate this on my own.

Comment: Updated answer: "Partly is calculated by physical doppler shift effect, but the exact technik is not published. "